# Concat multiple lists from a list element for element for the sublist

Tags: python, list

Given:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['1', '2', '3'], ['Z', 'X']]
```

Is there a way to concatenate every element from the lists in the list for every index 1 to 1 not 1 to many without using a lot of for statements? And the output to be a list with every concatenation as its elements?

Expected output:

```
['A1Z','B2X', 'C3']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want to `zip` the lists together. But if the lists are not of the same length, we need to pad them. `itertools.zip_longest` helps us with that:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

xss = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['1', '2', '3'], ['Z', 'X']]
result = ["".join(xs) for xs in zip_longest(*xss, fillvalue="")]
```

Which gives:

```
>>> result
['A1Z', 'B2X', 'C3']
```

Answer (score 0):

A beginner-friendly solution

```
s = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['1', '2', '3'],['Z', 'X']]
f = []

n = 0
while n != len(s):
    t = ''
    for i in s:
        try: t = t + i[n]
        except IndexError: pass
    f.append(t)

    n = n + 1
print(f)
```